# "Column/Frame Breaks" vs "Keep Options"

Tags: adobe-indesign

If I directly add a Column/Frame Break after Paragraph break. it would be create a new line to place the break. I can't style 2 breaks in one line. The Keep Options do not like that but I should set them in the Paragraph styles. Anyone have better ideas?

Comment: You "could" insert your column/frame break instead of a Paragraph break. But I strongly recommend using Keep Options. No better idea than this perfect feature

Comment: Thank you Vinny! I just think it's not enough for me.

Comment: It's hard to know if Keep Options could be used, when we do not have an example. Is there a pattern/logic to where you want to break the column? If not , I'm afraid you have to add that extra line (I don't like it either). You could also use invisible frames with text wrap to force a column break, but it's a bit messy.

Comment: Now I use the Keep Options with Paragraph Style settings for priority  option. I prefer to keep the contents seperated from styles. Thanks Wolff!